# How to play a song from a specified playlist (Spotify API)

Tags: python, api, spotify, put

I want to play all the songs of a given playlist using the spotify API in python. I have got the access token and the required stuff, but am getting a response of 403, the first method `find_songs` returns my playlist and it returns a response of 200, but not the second method

```
class SaveSongs:
def __init__(self):
    self.user_id = spotify_user_id
    self.spotify_token = ""
    self.playlist_id = playlist_id
    self.tracks = ""
    self.new_playlist_id = ""
    self.device_id = "DESKTOP-9UBFPPN"

def find_songs(self):
    print("Finding songs in your playlist...")
    query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{}/tracks".format(
        playlist_id)
    response = requests.get(query,
                            headers={"Content-Type": "application/json",
                                     "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(self.spotify_token)})
    response_json = response.json()
    print(response)

def call_refresh(self):
    print("Refreshing token")
    refreshCaller = Refresh()
    self.spotify_token = refreshCaller.refresh()
    self.find_songs()

def playSong(self): #issue here
    query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play"
    response = requests.put(query,
                            headers={"Content-Type": "application/json",
                                    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(self.spotify_token)}, data={
        "context_uri": "spotify:playlist:7mnkglhHfzZRYFRG72zCMd"
    })

    print(response)

a = SaveSongs()
a.call_refresh()
a.playSong()
```

Refresh.py:

```
class Refresh:

def __init__(self):
    self.refresh_token = refresh_token
    self.base_64 = base_64

def refresh(self):

    query = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

    response = requests.post(query,
                             data={"grant_type": "refresh_token",
                                   "refresh_token": refresh_token},
                             headers={"Authorization": "Basic " + base_64})

    response_json = response.json()
    print(response_json)

    return response_json["access_token"]


a = Refresh()
a.refresh()
```

cURL command

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic " -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code= -d redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FRohith-JN https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

get request to get the code for curl command:

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FRohith-JN&scope=playlist-modify-public%20playlist-modify-private%20user-modify-playback-state
```

expired access token:

```
BQDbYxNY8h2Crof2_aE1-Tzgk0fnQ5EHBjenqM1dmExNpmbEaw5Ra548kEM86vSLeZ9XTuHLgRXRxxgLQF1aXcqcpUivuaEBjQSmjRFfeBGazCdVxSZQgCMDR_XRa5PhhrVebE2gYfDQl468BkSEGSGWV5LJ2EOYbWS5fsCTHWt-XtM7TFEDQJw3J43yiYf98pBWggp7CQM_yv31XLjoNe93A-j-rwQEJQ0
```

Comment: can you post the code to `Refresh`?

Comment: The refresh method works and I get the new access token, the problem is I am not sure how to play a song from spotify using a put request

Comment: how did you get the refresh token in the first place?

Comment: I got the refresh token using curl

Comment: can you post that cURL command as well?

Comment: I have updated the question with the cURL command

Comment: This is "authorization-code" grant type of Oauth. Didn't you get redirected to Spotify login screen when you triggered this command?

Comment: provide one more argument in your curl command. "-d scope=user-modify-playback-state"

Comment: First I did a get request to get the code which I copied and then paste into the curl command, so in the first get request itself I specified the scope not in the curl command

Comment: cool! did it work?

Comment: No I am still getting a response of 403

Comment: Is there anything wrong in `playSong` function?

Comment: can you send me the access token? an expired one will do

Comment: I updated the question with the expired access token

Comment: Oh, looks like the token isn't JWT. There's not much we can do. If it was JWT, we could inspect the token to look for the scopes

Comment: I see some issues in your cURL command to get the code. The hyphens need to be url encoded. I think %2d needs to replace all hyphens. Special note to "Rohit-JN"

Comment: But if the curl command was wrong in the first place then would the find_songs method have worked? The find_songs method returns my playlist without any error

Comment: I get this error: `{'error': {'status': 403, 'message': 'Player command failed: Premium required', 'reason': 'PREMIUM_REQUIRED'}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241611/discussion-between-rohith-nambiar-and-d-b-k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was not with my code, For some calls such as play/pause, increase or decrease volume require a Spotify premium account.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to hit [this](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/start-a-users-playback) API.
If you check the [Authorization Scopes Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/scopes/), it states that you need to include the required "scope" while you are requesting the access token.

This is how most Oauth systems work. To access a protected resource, you first get an access token. But you also state that you want to do say, read on a resource XYZ. The access token that you get will have restricted permissions to do just what you wanted to do ( even though you as a user have permissions to a lot of other things ).

Scroll down to [the scope that you need](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/scopes/#user-modify-playback-state), and include this scope while requesting the access token. I believe this can solve your issue.

Well, how did I know how to search for this scope? I looked up the URI you are trying to hit, and looked up the scopes for that URI.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I missed this scope, I have added the required scope, but am not sure what to specify in the request